# Codeigniter: dropdown "Year" part not showing up

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

```
foreach($books as $book) {
        $bID = $book->book_id;
        $bName = $book->book_name ;
        $desc = $book->description;
        $author = $book->author;
        $publisher = $book->publisher;
        $pages = $book->pages;
        $pDate = $book->publication_date;
        $price = $book->price;
        $status = $book->status;
        $quantity = $book->quantity;
        $genres = $book->genres;
        $reviews = $book->reviews;
    };


$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", $pDate);


$data = array(
              'name'        => 'pages',
              'id'          => 'pages',
              'value'       => $pages,
              'style'       => 'font-size:18px',
              'size'        => '35',
              'placeholder' => 'Pages',
            );
    echo form_input($data);
    echo "<br /><br />";

    $months = array('' => 'Month',
                 '1'  => 'Jan',
                 '2'  => 'Feb',
                 '3'  => 'Mar',
                 '4'  => 'Apr',
                 '5'  => 'May',
                 '6'  => 'Jun',
                 '7'  => 'Jul',
                 '8'  => 'Aug',
                 '9'  => 'Sep',
                 '10' => 'Oct',
                 '11' => 'Nov',
                 '12' => 'Dec'
                );
         $days[''] = 'Day';         
         for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++){
            $days[$i] = $i;
         }

         $start_year = date("Y",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y")-80));
         $years[''] = 'Year';

         for ($i=$start_year;$i<=date("Y");++$i) {
            $years[$i] = $i;
         }
    echo form_label('Publication Date','pDate')."<br/>".
        form_dropdown('days',$days, $date->format("d"), 'required="required"'). " " . form_dropdown('months',$months, $date->format("m"), 'required="required"'). " " . form_dropdown('years',$years, $date->format("Y"), 'required="required"');
    echo "<br /><br />";
```

May i know why doesn't my Year part show up any value, however the Day and Month part are showing up at the dropdown menu and everything is working fine except for the year part. How could i solve it?

Comment: try to print_r $years check year has values or not

Comment: Yes my Year does have value however it is only not showing up, i tried by echoing this  echo $date->format("Y"); and the value came out too.

Comment: try to echo them separately do not concat them

Comment: Tried but does not work